# Algebra: Cross Multiplying with a Twist

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I do not understand the math when it comes to [this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBvsk.jpg). Can someone explain?

Comment: 1. It would be helpful if you could write the given problem, so that other users don't need to follow a link to see what you're struggling with.

Comment: It should probably not be moved to Physics. The confusion appears to be about the algebraic manipulations, not the physics involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, at some point you defined $\rho_{dry}=1.8 g/cc$ and $\rho_p=2.7 g/cc$.

In the first line, these values were substituted in, to get the second line.

In the second line, we divided both sides by $2.7g/cc$ to get
$$\frac{1.8 g/cc}{2.7g/cc} = 1-n$$

The LHS simplifies to $2/3$. Now subtract 1 from both sides to get $-1/3=-n$ and so $n=1/3$, which is what the third line says.

Comment: So you divided both sides by 2.7g/cc to isolate the 1-n? Ok got it. Thanks.